# XAML not recognizing class in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this callback in my XAML file:

```
<UserControl xmlns:myLocal="clr-namespace:Shadow_App"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="900" Width="1000" x:Name="window">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <myLocal:SumOtherCategoryConverter x:Key="SumOtherCategoryConverter"/>
```

And I have this code in my code-behind:

```
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Shadow_App
{
    public class SumOtherCategoryConverter : IValueConverter
    {
```

I keep on getting the error at `<myLocal:SumOtherCategoryConverter x:Key="SumOtherCategoryConverter"/>`:

The name "SumOtherCategoryConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Shadow_App".

What am I doing wrong? WPF even completes myLocal: to myLocal:SumOtherCategoryConverter when I type it. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, and when rebuilding it gives me the error:

The tag 'SumOtherCategoryConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Shadow_App'. Line 14 Position 10.

Comment: Is the `SumOtherCategoryConverter` in the same assembly as your user control?

Comment: They're all in the same project. The code-behind and the xaml are attached (I think that's what you're asking).

Comment: Then have you build your project?

Comment: I tried cleaning the project. It cleans, but fails to rebuild.

Comment: @Sean does it not build purely because of this error or you have some other errors elsewhere? If you have other errors fix those first

Comment: I am sure. It fails to build and says:

Comment: The tag 'SumOtherCategoryConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Shadow_App'. Line 14 Position 10.

Comment: Build your project and look if you don't have a compile error somewhere else

Comment: Try commenting out the converter in XAML and building again.  Sometimes WPF's odd "double compile" behavior trips it up when referencing things within the same project.  If it compiles with the line commented out, try adding it back and compiling again.

Comment: You didn't show your code for the converter, there must be some error in there and it cannot compile.

Comment: I commented out the line, it compiled, and the uncommented out the line and it doesn't compile. I put no code in the converter, put working code in (I tried it in another program), and neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think your namespace is not properly defined that's why you have got the error. I have implemented your code and works fine.

Comment: What do you mean? How do I appropriately define my namespace?